# Why typing in Eclipse/PyDev editor became very slow?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

Recently, typing python code in PyDev editors became extremely slow. Slow to the point that after typing a function name I have to wait to see letters appear one after another over several seconds. Even inside comments and strings. Other editors are fine.

I tried suggestions in other questions like disabling automatic building but got no effect.

Restarting Eclipse does not resolve the problem but after a reboot the situation is better.

I'm running PyDev 3.9.2/Eclipse 4.4.2 with Oracle Java 1.8 64bit on CentOS 7. Eclipse is started with `-Xms512m` and `-Xmx2048m`. The System is an old Intel Core i7 with 8GB Ram.

[image: Here is my current installed Plugin]

I appreciate any suggestions to find the problem cause.

*Update:* Still have the same issue with PyDev v4.1. I filed a bug report on the [PyDev issue tracker: ID 582](https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/582)

*Update 2:* The bug was fixed in PyDev v4.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it seems that different reasons can cause it, but turning off vertical guidelines solved it for me:

Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Vertical Indent Guide -> Show vertical indent guide set to False

Comment: Thanks a lot. Deactivating indentation guide fixed the problem. I hope this problem get fixed as the indentation guide is very helpful.

Comment: For those affected, I just took a tentative fix at this (as I wasn't able to reproduce it here) and updated the nightly build... can you update it there and let me know if it works for you?

http://pydev.org/download.html has details on the update site url for the nightly build.

Comment: This wasn't the fix for me after all, it was Code Completion -> auto completion delay -> set to 1 (was at 0)

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing the same thing on RHEL6 with Eclipse 4.4.2 and PyDev 3.9.2. It got better when I turned off the compositing features in KDE.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm actually using Gnome. I'll try to find if I can change similar options in Gnome.

Comment: I'm using windows and I see the same thing. It does depend on file size slightly, but can be extremely slow even for relatively small files. I'm on PyDev 4